# Access variable dataframe in R loop

Tags: r, loops, variables, dataframe

If I am working with dataframes in a loop, how can I use a variable data frame name (and additionally, variable column names) to access data frame contents?

```
dfnames <- c("df1","df2")

df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(X = sample(1:10),Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))

for (i in seq_along(dfnames)){
    curr.dfname <- dfnames[i]

    #how can I do this:
    curr.dfname$X <- 42:52

    #...this
    dfnames[i]$X <- 42:52

    #or even this doubly variable call
    for (j in 1_seq_along(colnames(curr.dfname)){
        curr.dfname$[colnames(temp[j])] <- 42:52
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the two data frames in a named list.

Comment: @joran, like, `dflist<-c(df1,df2)`, then access it like `dflist[i]$X<-42` ? trouble is those dfs are created in that loop. I could do a second set though if needs be.

Comment: No. list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2), and you can use [[ to access either by name or position. You should read up on lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get()` to return a variable reference based on a string of its name:

```
> x <- 1:10
> get("x")
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So, yes, you could iterate through `dfnames` like:

```
dfnames <- c("df1","df2")
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(X = sample(1:10), Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))

for (cur.dfname in dfnames)
{
    cur.df <- get(cur.dfname)

    # for a fixed column name
    cur.df$X <- 42:52

    # iterating through column names as well
    for (j in colnames(cur.df))
    {
        cur.df[, j] <- 42:52
    }
}
```

I really think that this is gonna be a painful approach, though. As the commenters say, if you can get the data frames into a list and then iterate through that, it'll probably perform better and be more readable. Unfortunately, `get()` isn't vectorised as far as I'm aware, so if you only have a string list of data frame names, you'll have to iterate through that to get a data frame list:

```
# build data frame list
df.list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(dfnames))
{
    df.list[[i]] <- get(dfnames[i])
}

# iterate through data frames
for (cur.df in df.list)
{
    cur.df$X <- 42:52
}
```

Hope that helps!

**2018 Update:** I probably wouldn't do something like this anymore. Instead, I'd put the data frames in a list and then use `purrr:map()`, or, the base equivalent, `lapply()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

stuff_to_do = function(mydata) {
  mydata$somecol = 42:52
            # … anything else I want to do to the current data frame
  mydata    # return it  
}

df_list = list(df1, df2)
map(df_list, stuff_to_do)
```

This brings back a list of modified data frames (although you can use variants of `map()`, `map_dfr()` and `map_dfc()`, to automatically bind the list of processed data frames row-wise or column-wise respectively. The former uses column names to join, rather than column positions, and it can also add an ID column using the `.id` argument and the names of the input list. So it comes with some nice added functionality over `lapply()`!

Comment: This was a helpful answer! How do I unlist the dataframes that were manipulated in the function? (Note: some of the dataframes themselves contain lists, so `list2env(cur.df ,.GlobalEnv)` is going to be problematic.)

Comment: I definitely wouldn't do this anymore! Gimme half an hour to find some breakfast and I'll give you a more modern answer?

Comment: That would be amazing! This is 100% applicable to what I am doing right now :)

Comment: I've popped it on the end of my answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much! So, many of the columns in the dataframe are unique and need to be processed separately - but some of the transformations of variables are the same, which is why I'm trying to write this function. I am struggling to extract the `df` in a list individually - i.e. get back to `df1`, df2` being separate. Do you have a sense of how to do that?

Comment: I think in that case you might want to look at some of the scoped functions in the dplyr package, like `mutate_at()` or `mutate_if()`. The idea is that you write your transformations as functions (one vector in, one vector out) and then you can either apply the transformation to columns that pass a predicate test, like `is.character` (for m `mutate_if()`) or ones whose name you've selected using a helper, like `starts_with("blah")` or `one_of(vector_of_column_names)` (for `mutate_at()`). This way everything still status separate and it's obvious later on why you did those things :)

Comment: Oops! Here's the link to those scoped functions: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html